# Powershell print all ascii chars

Tags: powershell, ascii

I'm trying to make a simple loop to generate a password using only ascii symbols, I'm also trying to exclude whitespace from the print, here what I got so far

```
33 .. 126 | %{ " $([char]$_)" }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what the desired output is?

Comment: password = %$%#&*@#$%*><#%!*(

Comment: So you want to randomly select a certain number of chars to form a password?

Comment: I have edited the post, issue is number 44 seems to be blank

Comment: There are slightly more than 90 characters in `33 .. 126` but you want a password of 18 characters... can you explain?

Comment: ASCII 44 is the comma `,` not blank.. Perhaps you want to read [this Password Guidance](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Microsoft_Password_Guidance-1.pdf)

Comment: [There are tons of pre-built random password generator written in PowerShell all over the web to learn from or use as is](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+random+password+generator%27&t=hk&ia=web). As well as modules in the Microsoft powershellgallery.com to use.   [Find-Module -Name '*password*' | Format-Table -AutoSize] .   Unless this is a learning exercise, homework assignment, why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate a password from a specific set of characters, [`Get-Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-random) is your friend:

```
function New-Password 
{
  param(
    [int]$Length = 18
  )

  $characterSet = 33..126 -as [char[]]
  $password = ''
  1..18 |% {
    $password += $characterSet |Get-Random
  }

  return $password
}
```

> I'm also trying to exclude whitespace

No need to worry as long as you don't *insert* any, there are no whitespace characters in the range you're generating characters from

Comment: It would be a nice modification to be able to expressively select which special characters can be used. This may be more tricky as they are occupying different ranges of the ASCII list.

Comment: @not2qubit you can filter the `$characterSet` as you please, ie. `33..126 -as [char[]] |? {$_ -cnotin ('abcdef0123456789:$'.ToCharArray())}`

Answer (score 2):

Along with @Mathias R. Jessen helpful answer.

You have spaces because that is what you asked for....

```
33 .. 126 | %{ " $([char]$_)" }
```

... note that space between the double quote and the dollar sign, vs this

```
33 .. 126 | %{ "$([char]$_)" }
```

So a one-liner would work as well...

```
((33..126 | %{ "$([char]$_)" } | Get-Random -Count 18) -join '')
# Results
<#
,KoC]^>=3'hIsnG_Ub
#>
```

Yet again, Mathias R. Jessen response, is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the *Title* for this question is wrong, considering the actual ask (password), I will address the title.

Here is your **posh-ascii-table**:

```
# Define Non-printable range: ASCII 0-32,127
$Q = @('[NUL]','[SOH]','[STX]','[ETX]','[EOT]','[ENQ]','[ACK]','[BEL]','[BS]','[HT]','[LF]','[VT]','[FF]','[CR]','[SO]','[SI]','[DLE]','[DC1]','[DC2]','[DC3]','[DC4]','[NAK]','[SYN]','[ETB]','[CAN]','[EM]','[SUB]','[ESC]','[FS]','[GS]','[RS]','[US]','[SP]','[DEL]')

# Define InvalidFileNameChars list:
$W=@([int[]] [System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars() |sort)

1..127 | %{ Write-Host -Fo DarkGray ("{0,3}  {0:x2}  " -f $_,[int]($_)) -Non; $c = $([char]$_); if ($_ -in (0..32)) {$c = $Q[$_]; Write-Host -Fo DarkYellow "${c}"; return;} elseif ($_ -eq 127) {$c = $Q[33]; Write-Host -Fo Red "${c}"; return;} elseif ($_ -in $W) {Write-Host -Fo Red "${c}"; return;} ; Write-Host -Fo White "${c}";}
```

This will show the following output:

- All printable characters prefixed with both their ASCII *decimal* and *hexadecimal* codes.
- All *non-printable* characters as `DarkYellow` with their ASCII Name
- All *invalid* Filename Characters as `Red`. (Obviously the above can't be used)
- With the *Delete* character as `[DEL]` also in Red.

[image]

<sub>This is now part of my custom posh startup and the only exercise remaining,

is how to output this in a table form with 4 columns of 32 characters...</sub>

**NOTE**

> ASCII codes between `0x80` and `0xFF` are referred to as an "**Extended ASCII table**". (See [here](https://www.ascii-code.com/).) However, the characters within that extended table varies in the range `0x80-0x9F`, depending on what PC/terminal character set *encoding* is used, **and** what *fonts* have been installed to support those codes.